# Understanding KGf.CM in Camera Robotic Head Design

Tags: robotic-arm, motor, torque

I am attempting to design a robotic camera head - however, I am struggling to calculate the torque (in terms of KGf.CM) I will require to rotate the Y (tilt) axis of the head.

The motor I intend to use is rated at 40KGf.cm at 30RPM - however, I do not know by how many centimetres I should divide the 40KG to determine my head capacity when factoring in the height of the camera and it's centre of mass.

To explain myself better, please see this image:

[image: Camera Head]

Considering the centre mass of the camera (let's say 10KG) exactly lines up with the motor, can I leave the the equation to stand at 1CM - or do I need to factor in the 10CM drop to the bottom of the camera basket?

Many Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 1):

> Considering the centre mass of the camera (let's say 10KG) exactly lines up with the motor, can I leave the the equation to stand at 1CM - or do I need to factor in the 10CM drop to the bottom of the camera basket?

I don't know what you mean by "leav[ing] the equation to stand at 1 cm," because I'm not sure where the 1 cm is coming from. If the center of mass of the camera is in-line with the motor shaft, then there should be no static torque required to hold the camera in any particular position.

You'll still have to deal with the moment of inertia of the camera, which has more to do with mass *distribution* than with the mass itself; the moment of inertia will determine how quickly you can change speeds (i.e., how long it takes to get from stopped to 30 rpm and back to stopped).